# User Form Command Button to embed hyperlink to spreadsheet database

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I have a simple spreadsheet database where the second column of every row contains a hyperlink to a pdf. Each Hyperlink is unique for each row.

I want to add a command button to a user form that when clicked, allows the user to browse to the correct pdf and embed it as a hyperlink into the spreadsheet database in the correct cell. (cell 2 or every row in my case)

I know how to create a label that will follow the hyperlink once it is in the cell, but I am totally stuck on how to embed the hyperlink in the first place!

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Record a macro while creating a hyperlink: that will give you the code you need.  You can use `Application.GetOpenFileName` to allow the user to select a file.

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment to Tim Williams but its too hard to format.

Thanks for your suggestion to record a macro, it gave me some clues as to what to do. I now have a working solution, but it is quite ugly.

```
Private Sub AddHyper_button_Click()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Hyperlink_textbox = URL
End Sub

Private Sub Hyperlink_Label_Click()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim cellvalue As Variant

    cellvalue = Hyperlink_textbox.Value
    URL = cellvalue

    On Error GoTo urlnotopen
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=URL, NewWindow:=True
    Exit Sub
urlnotopen:
    MsgBox "Cannot open " & URL
End Sub
```

This finds the file address on button click, posts it to a text box on the form (which is hidden) which can be then written to the correct cell. There is also a label on the form which will follow the hyperlink to the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the selection in a textbox, unless you really want to.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As String
    x = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Label1 = x

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Me.Label1, NewWindow:=True
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Label1
        .ForeColor = vbBlue
    End With

End Sub
```

Here is a short clip on this.
[UserForm HyperLink](https://youtu.be/YgbhX1DFRDM)